# SQL Server - EXEC() at DB_LINK Issue

Tags: sql-server, remote-server

The following query to a linked server produces the expected results:

```
SELECT * FROM DB_LINK.[DB].[dbo].[TABLE1]
```

I expect the following to return the same result:

```
EXEC('SELECT * FROM [DB].[dbo].[TABLE1]') AT DB_LINK
```

But instead it produces error 18482:

```
Could not connect to server 'B' because 'A' is not defined as a remote server.
Verify that you have specified the correct server name.
```

[According to Microsoft](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/217395/you-receive-an-error-18482-error-message-when-you-try-to-make-a-remote):

> If an entry with srvid = 0 is not found in sysservers, or if the server name with srvid = 0 belongs to a server name that is different from the local Windows NT computer name, you will receive the error.

However, neither of problem conditions exist in my situation and the problem persists.

In fact, I can perform this `EXEC` command on other database links at it works without issue, e.g. the following works fine to a different link:

```
EXEC('SELECT * FROM [DB].[dbo].[TABLE1]') AT DB_LINK2
```

I also read [this article](http://www.cryer.co.uk/brian/sqlserver/ssem_cncd.htm), but again it says this error is caused by renaming the server after SQL server was installed, but this isn't true in my case. The following command verifies that the server is named correctly (on both the local and remote server):

```
select @@SERVERNAME
go
```

Therefore I believe it is a problem with the remote server, not the local server, since I can use this `EXEC` command on other database links.

Does anyone know what else could cause this issue?

P.S. The reason that the `EXEC` command is desirable is because I want to perform a `JOIN` of two remote tables. I've found that performing the `JOIN` with the `DB_LINK.[DB].[dbo].[TABLE1]` method is slower than the remote server performing the `JOIN` via `EXEC`.

Comment: Check the bottom section of this article: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1757/dynamic-sql-execution-on-remote-sql-server-using-exec-at/

Comment: @Alex Which part? The section that discusses the error _Server 'myserver' is not configured for RPC_? That isn't the error I am experiencing.

Comment: Have you tried the old "turning it off and on again" trick, that is, recreating the linked server completely with `sp_dropserver` and `sp_addlinkedserver`?

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/170914/sql-server-linked-server-error-could-not-connect-to-server-xyz-because